# Appending a value to a tuple

Tags: c++11

I have a tuple:

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, bool> foo = { 10, "Hello, world!", false };
```

and I have a single variable of some type:

```
MyClass bar;
```

How should I go about writing a generic function that appends a single value (or even multiple values, if possible) into a new tuple?

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, bool, MyClass> fooBar = tuple_append(foo, bar);
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                            // I need this magical function!
```

Comment: Can't you simply use [`tuple_cat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`std::tuple_cat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) (as already commented by [Zeta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139697/zeta)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, std::string, bool> foo { 10, "Hello, world!", false };

    auto foo_ext = std::tuple_cat(foo, std::make_tuple('a'));

    std::cout << std::get<0>(foo_ext) << "\n"
              << std::get<1>(foo_ext) << "\n"
              << std::get<2>(foo_ext) << "\n"
              << std::get<3>(foo_ext) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
10
Hello, world!
0
a
```

See http://ideone.com/dMLqOu.

Answer (score 7):

For appending a single element, this will work:

```
template <typename NewElem, typename... TupleElem>
std::tuple<TupleElem..., NewElem> tuple_append(const std::tuple<TupleElem...> &tup, const NewElem &el) {
    return std::tuple_cat(tup, std::make_tuple(el));
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/3mYg36)